# Vb.net Using Public Sub to Open Instance of MDI Child

Tags: vb.net, mdichild, mdiparent

I am trying lessen the line of code by creating a Public Sub calling in one line. However the form.MdiParent = Me generates error

frmParatemers is a Mdi Child form. frmMain is the MDI parent form.

From frmMain form

```
Dim MyCtrl As MenuClickOperations    
MyCtrl.showChildDialog(New frmParameters)
```

This is my Class MenuClickOperations

```
Public Sub showChildDialog(ByVal form As Form)
    Dim form2 As Form
    For Each form2 In frmMain.MdiChildren
        form2.Close()
    Next
    form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    form.MinimizeBox = False
    form.MaximizeBox = False
    form.MdiParent = Me
    form.Show()
End Sub
```

Help me..Thanks

Comment: The `MdiParent` of child form has to be a form.  If that code is not inside a form then `Me` does not refer to a form and is therefore not a valid value for `MdiParent`.

Comment: How can I resolve sir?

Comment: You can resolve the issue by actually assigning the parent form to the `MdiParent` property of the child form.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `form.MdiParent = Me` with `form.MdiParent = formInstance`. You can use `frmMain`, or the instance of frmMain (if different). If showChildDialog is called from frmMain, you can pass the frmMain instance as a parameter using `Me` in the call.

Comment: Thanks, I realized passing parameter in Me Control

Answer (score 0):

in frmMain

```
Dim MyCtrl As MenuClickOperations    
MyCtrl.showChildDialog(New frmParameters, Me)
```

This is my Class MenuClickOperations

```
Public Sub showChildDialog(ByVal form As Form, ByVal Itself As Control)
Dim form2 As Form
For Each form2 In frmMain.MdiChildren
    form2.Close()
Next
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
form.MinimizeBox = False
form.MaximizeBox = False
form.MdiParent = Itself
form.Show()
End Sub
```